# ActionController::BadRequest (Invalid request parameters: expected Array (got Rack::QueryParser::Params) for param `columns')

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, haml

I want a user to be able to check off a column and pick various formats thorough a select tag. This is what it looks like [image]
However, when I submit the form I get that error and I can't seem to figure out what is wrong.

```
= form_tag table_update_columns_path(table), :method => :post do
%table.table.table-hover.table-striped.table-bordered.data-table{:style => "width: 600px;"}
    %tr
        %th Column
        %th Data Type
        %th Format
    - table.get_columns.each do |k,v|
        %tr
            %td.createOrQueryColumns
                = hidden_field_tag "table[columns][#{k}]", "false"
                %span= check_box_tag "table[columns][#{k}]", "true", (v == "true" ? true : false)
                %h6= k
            %td
                = hidden_field_tag "table[data_types][#{k}]", ""
                - if table.data_types.nil?
                    = select_tag "table[data_types][#{k}]", options_for_select(Table.data_types), { :class => 'form-control input-sm' }
                -else
                    = select_tag "table[data_types][#{k}]", options_for_select(Table.data_types, table.data_types[k]), { :class => 'form-control input-sm' }
            %td
                = hidden_field_tag "table[formats][#{k}]", ""
                - if table.formats.nil?
                    = select_tag "table[formats][#{k}]", options_for_select(Table.formats), { :class => 'form-control input-sm' }
                -else
                    = select_tag "table[formats][#{k}]", options_for_select(Table.formats, table.formats[k]), { :class => 'form-control input-sm' }
= submit_tag "Save", :class => "btn form-control btn-primary"
```

Comment: Looks like you need to use the ```f``` that you set in form for. Instead of hidden_field_tag or check_box_tag, you should do ```f.hidden_field``` and so on.

Comment: I tried changing everything to form_tag but it still gives me the same error, updated post